# Is there a callback or any other way to execute a function after the jQuery mmenu has plugin finished activation?

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I'm firing the plugin on click.

```
$('#activate_mmenu').on('click', function(){
    $('#menu').mmenu();
});
```

is there a way to bind another function after the plugin has been activated?

something like this:

```
$('#activate_mmenu').on('click', function(){
    $('#menu').mmenu(function(){
        alert('plugin is activated!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Mmenu triggers it's own events

```
$("#nav")
   .mmenu()
   .trigger( "mmenu-created" )
);
```

more information is available here: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/events.php

Edit: Had removed the wrong part of the code. You can trigger an event right after the mmenu initialisation.

Comment: This would trigger the alert when the menu opened. If I understand the question correct, it should be triggered right after the plugin was fired.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have taken out the wrong code part: See the page for a solution but also take into account, that this is version 4 of the library that is not that stable anymore, in my opinion.

Comment: I can't see any reference to a 'menu-created' event in the docs. Still unclear from you answer how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#activate_mmenu').on('click', function(){
    $("#menu")
        .mmenu()
        .on('init', function(){
            console.log('init');
        })
        .trigger( "init" );
});
```

The documentation doesn't say a ton about custom events, but I got this to work. Then trigger it. As a result, you can simulate callbacks on initialization.

At first I created the custom event and bound it to the .mm namespace as recommended in the docs, but that doesn't appear to be necessary.